# Custom background image with ggmap

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

I'm using R and ggmap to analyse some geographic data. I would like to use my own background map (a tif file) instead of the ones provided by ggmap (google maps, osm, stamen, etc.).

Is there a way to load my own raster file and display it using ggmap ? I really want to keep ggmap as most of my analysis use ggmap's functions (geom_density2d, geom_tile, etc.). For example a wrapper that transform a raster file reads by the raster package to a ggmap get_map object ?

Thanks

Comment: have you tried annotation_raster or annotation_custom?

Comment: Hi baptiste. Yeap I've tried but while I am able to display my raster it only shows a few colors of the raster. II don't know why I'm not able to display the raster as it is.

Comment: Another solution could be also to work with the raster package as it is able to display my raster. But I don't know then how to plot my ggmap results on the top of a raster produced by the raster package.